# How to handle Facebook's signed_request for iFrame Canvas applications?

Tags: facebook, cakephp, iframe, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an iFrame Canvas application for Facebook using CakePHP, its Auth component, WebTechNick's [Facebook plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/wtn/blogs/view/238/Facebook_Plugin_v2_0_Graph_System) and OAuth for canvas pages (I've enabled this in the Facebook Developer app options). I would like users to be able to use the application after adding it to their profile (by requesting `email` and `publish_stream` permissions) by visiting http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ or as a tab in their profile.

Requesting permissions is not the problem. The user is redirected to the permissions request page and then redirected to a callback method which requests an `access_token`, as per this [tutorial](http://kartiklad.com/oauth-2-0-and-graph-api-for-facebook-canvas-applications/).

After this callback the user is redirected back to http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ which shows their personal index page. This is also where the problems start. As soon as the aforementioned URI is loaded, the browser asks for a form resubmission, this happens every time I reload http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/. This is the case because Facebook wants to pass the (expected) `signed_request` parameter and I'm wondering what to do with it. It's not an empty variable, so do I need another validation method or redirect, perhaps?

How should I handle the procedure for the `signed_request` parameter and, more importantly how to get rid of this form resubmission dialog?

Some of my methods, they might be a bit of a mess due to all the experimentation of the past day.

`beforeFilter`, `login` and `callback` methods, in my UserController.php:

```
  function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if (empty($this->permissions)) {
      $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout', 'callback');
    }
  }

  function login() {
    $session = $this->facebook->getSession();
    $login_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . MY_APP_URL . '/users/callback/&type=user_agent&&display=page&scope=' . FACEBOOK_APP_PERMISSIONS;
    if($session){
      try {
        $uid = $facebook_client->getUser();
        $me  = $facebook_client->api('/me', $params);
        print($me);
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
      }
        } else {
      $this->set('authorise', true);
      $script = '$(document).ready(function() { facebookRequestPermissions("'.$login_url.'");});';
      $this->set('script', $script);
        }
  }

  function callback() {
    function callFb($url, $params) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    $params=array('client_id'=>FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'type'=>'client_cred', 'client_secret'=>FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
    $access_token = callFb($url, $params);
    $access_token = substr($access_token, strpos($access_token, "=")+1, strlen($access_token));

    if ($access_token) {
      $this->redirect(FACEBOOK_APP_URL);
    } else {
      echo 'An error has occurred';
    }
  }
```

The JavaScript in the login method refers to this jQuery function, the Facebook JavaScript SDK is initialised in `$(document).ready()`:

```
function facebookRequestPermissions(login_url) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status !== 'unknown') {
      top.location.href=login_url;
    }
  });
}
```

The JavaScript function should only fire when a user is logged in, if not, a different landing page is shown.

I use some methods in an overall AppControler:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  var $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Auth', 'Facebook.Connect');
  var $helpers = array('Form', 'Time','Html','Javascript', 'Session', 'Facebook.Facebook');
  protected $facebook;
  protected $permissions;
  private $user;

  function beforeRender() {
    //Save the username if it isn't already present
    if ((int)$this->Auth->user('id') != '' && (string)$this->Auth->user('username') == '') {
      $data = array('id' => (int)$this->Auth->user('id'), 'username' => (string)$this->user['username']);
      $this->loadModel('User');
      $this->User->save($data);
    }
    if (!empty($this->user) && !empty($this->permissions)) {
      $this->set('currentUser', $this->Auth->user());
    }
  }

  function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    App::import('Lib', 'Facebook.FB');
    $this->facebook = new FB();
    $this->user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    $this->permissions = $this->facebook->api('/me/permissions');
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
This only seems an issue with Firefox. Chrome doesn't display the dialog, but instead does a silent refresh after which the `signed_request` parameter is empty, strangely enough. This isn't the case with Firefox, where the `signed_request` parameter remains the same after every prompted refresh (unless the iFrame content is cached), which is looping infinitely, it seems.

**EDIT 2:**
Still struggling with this, but I ended up disabling the *OAuth 2.0 for Canvas* option in the Facebook Developer application, which has resolved the form resubmission issue. Of course this is not a real solution, because OAuth 2.0 is becoming mandatory for canvas application on Facebook, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't test the whole thing I am not sure if this is right, but on the first sight your JavaScript function looks strange to me. It looks like you always redirect to the login url, although the user gave permission.

Refering to [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), the function should look like this:

```
function facebookRequestPermissions(login_url) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (!response.session) {
      top.location.href=login_url;
    }
  });
}
```

or, if you want to call `.status`:

```
if (response.status == 'unknown')
```

About your question concerning the `signed_request`: it is used to get some information, look at [Authentication - Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) to see what exactly. You don't need another validation method.

Comment: You're right that the function doesn't look the way it should. The "unknown" status is returned when a user isn't logged in. I only want the application to redirect when a user is logged into Facebook and hasn't added the application. The JS function isn't fired when a user has already added the application and will not redirect when the user isn't logged in. Tinkering with this function doesn't get rid of the form resubmission dialog, unfortunately.